# Does S3 MFA delete prevent the bucket itself from being deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with MFA delete on S3 and it's unclear from the documentation whether enabling MFA delete will prevent the bucket itself from being deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete a bucket as long as the bucket has *any* objects in it... to delete a bucket requires that all the objects be deleted first... so whether or not you can delete the bucket itself with MFA delete enabled seems somewhat immaterial, though MFA delete doesn't appear to prevent bucket deletion per se.

It is also possible to require an IAM user to authenticate with MFA.  If users with permission to delete the bucket all require MFA, then the bucket's existence is protected that way.  MFA Delete and IAM with MFA are different features.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret [this line of the MFA delete documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete) to mean that NO, you can't delete the bucket itself, only the objects within:

> You configure MFA Delete on a bucket to ensure that data in your bucket cannot be accidentally deleted.

The fact that MFA Delete falls under s3 object versioning would add weight to this.

In any case, you should log a documentation bug.

p.s. for some empirical peace of mind, you could also try deleting a bucket via MFA